# Does the ratio test fail in testing $\frac{n}{n^2+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

[image: series test]

The exercise requires me to use the ratio test to check for the convergence or divergence of the series but since the limit evaluates to 1, l don't see any way out of it. I think it should approach infinity or be greater than 1.I also tried plugging the limit into wolfram math and it also came out as 1.

Any other trick to try on this test ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct!

Comment: @Robert Z  Thanks for the help, l think the exercise will contain  more series that will fail the test.

Comment: The ratio test and the root test are both inconclusive.  Which then suggests a different test such as the comparison test is in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that the ratio test fails to determine whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n^2 + 1}$ converges. But a simple way to see that it diverges using a different check is to notice that since $1 \le n^2$ and $n > 0$, $\frac{n}{n^2 + 1} \ge \frac{n}{n^2 + n^2} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{n}$. Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n^2 + 1}$ is larger than half of it, your sum must diverge as well.